# RMI Connection Refuse connect

Tags: java, rmi

I have wrote an RMI Client and Server when i start then on a single PC all is working. When i start at my PC the Registry, the Server and a ChatServer.

On another PC in the Local Network I start the client, then i get the requests on the Server but after the Requests i get this Error:

**Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.178.49; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect**

Does this looks like a network promission error or a rmi-programming failure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently. If the address in the message is the same machine as the machine getting the error, the response is being sent to the wrong one. You have to manually set your own

```
java.rmi.server.hostname
```

in both applications. Otherwise it is probably a routing problem, that one of the machines is simply not reachable from the other.

Here is the link to the property: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html

Comment: You set it in the server JVM. Not in 'both applications'.

Comment: It must be in both applications, otherwise callbacks will not work.

Comment: There is nothing in the question about callbacks.

Comment: still its good practice to do it - and we do not know if there are callbacks. that does not mean there are none

Comment: It's not good practice to do something that has no effect. You only have to do it in the client *if* there are callbacks *and* there is NAT or an `/etc/hosts` misconfiguration.